# Is there any difference between Bravais lattice and primitive lattice?

Tags: solid-state-physics

So far I just had the first lecture in solid state physics...I am still confused if there is any difference between Bravais lattice and primitive lattice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bravais lattices are those that fill the whole space without any gaps or overlapping, by simply repeating the unit cell periodically. The whole lattice can be generated starting from one point by operating the translation vector
$$\vec{R}\ =\ n_1 {\bf{a_1}}\ +\ n_2 {\bf{a_2}}\ +\ n_3{\bf{a_3}} $$
where $(n_1,n_2,n_3)$ are integers and $({\bf{a_1}},{\bf{a_2}},{\bf{a_3}})$ are the basis vectors which span the lattice.

In three dimensions, there are exactly 14 types of Bravais lattices. A primitive lattice is one such example. A primitive lattice is generated by repeating a primitive unit cell, which contains a single lattice point.

An example of a primitve unit cell in three dimension would be a cube with lattice points only at the vertices. Now, each of these lattice points is shared by 8 unit cells (4 above, 4 below). So, in each unit cell, one lattice point is counted as $\frac{1}{8}$. Thus, the total no. of lattice points in each unit cell is $\frac{1}{8}\times 8\ =\ 1$

Comment: You just wrote what is written in wikipedia.. It didnt give me a clear picture of the difference between those two lattices.. How do I differentiate Bravais lattice from Primitive lattice?

Comment: Why is a cube centered on a base is not a bravais lattice? Translation vectors applied repeatedly can cover all the lattice points.. Still a base centered cubic is not a bravais lattice (as what i read in wikipedia).. Why is that so?

Comment: The main point is that all primitive lattices are Bravais lattices, not the other way round. Also, base centered cubic IS a Bravais lattice. In the base centered cubic, apart from the 8 atoms at the corners, you have one centered at two bases. So, there are $\frac{1}{2}\times2\ +\ \frac{1}{8}\times 8\ =\ 2$
atoms in each unit cell, unlike a primitve unit cell where you have only 1. That's why a base centered cubic is not a primitive lattice (also called simple cubic), but another kind of Bravais lattice. Just wrote whatever little I could learn in my undergraduate days. Hope this helps!

Comment: However, in the base centered cubic lattice, the atoms placed at the corners may be different from those placed at the center of the bases. That's why I chose not to refer to them as lattice points.

Answer (score 1):

A Bravais lattice is an infinite periodic array of points - essentially a mathematical construct. It can be characterized by primitive lattice vectors $\vec{a_1}, \vec{a_2}, \vec{a_3}$ such that for any integers $n_1, n_2, n_3$, the lattice vector $\vec{R} = n_1\vec{a_1} + n_2\vec{a_2} + n_3\vec{a_3}$ is a lattice point and each lattice vector can be expressed in such a form.

Physically, you get a crystal when you place an atom (or a group of atoms) at each lattice point. If you're placing a group of atoms (sometimes referred to as a motif), associating points to all atoms gives a non-Bravais lattice because not all atoms are at a position described by the general lattice vector $\vec{R}$. Such a lattice is more commonly known as a *lattice with a basis*.

It's not clear what you mean by primitive lattice. A *primitive unit cell* is a volume that contains exactly one lattice point, that when displaced by all possible lattice vectors $\vec{R}$ covers the volume of the entire lattice. For instance, the volume defined the primitive lattice vectors is a primitive unit cell. Another commonly used term is *conventional unit cell*, which is usually a convenient geometric shape that does not necessarily contain only one lattice point. So a non-Bravais lattice will also have a unit cell that would typically contain more than one atom (depending on the basis).

The terminology is understandably confusing, particularly in the beginning. I strongly recommend the book *Solid State Physics*, by Ashcroft and Mermin.

Answer (score 0):

This can often get confusing as physicists and mathematicians tend to have different definitions for lattices, Bravais lattices, unit cells and so on. In physics, we often use *lattice* to refer to any *periodic* [1] packing, while we use *Bravais lattice* to refer to mathematical lattices, namely [2]:

> A Lattice is an infinite set of points defined by integer sums of a
>   set of linearly independent primitive basis vectors.

Now I guess by primitive lattice, you meant primitive unit cells (let me know if otherwise). Unit cells [2]:

> A unit cell is the repeated motif which is the elementary building
>   block of the periodic crystal.

And a primitive unit cell [2]:

> A primitive unit cell for a periodic crystal is a unit cell containing
>   only a single lattice point.

---

**[1]**: A periodic packing can be thought of as a union of many translates of a lattice.

**[2]**: Simon, Steven H. The Oxford solid state basics. OUP Oxford, 2013.